# Redis CPU spike

Tags: redis, server

The problem is described and answered here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/egyA1xvhGfo

Unfortunately I do not fully understand the answer.

My concerns are if redis takes up 100% CPU every 5 minutes and if my server only has a single CPU (i.e. staging) would that mean it will freeze my httpd process every 5 minutes?

Would this not be of a concern if my server has multiple CPUs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the type of persistence you select, this will happen.  The reason is because the standard persist method ( fork and copy-on-write aka cow ) happens after x number of object changes ( or however you have it configured ) and will eat up a fair amount of I/O persisting the database to disk.  You'll want at least a spare core on your server for the persistence to happen but it's not so much actual CPU that's being utilized as it is the wait for the I/O.  Faster I/O will mitigate the impact of the db saves.

Comment: I have not been able to find any tutorials on how to change the type of persistence of redis to work around this problem.

Comment: http://redis.io/topics/persistence  explains the different methods pretty well and how to set them up

Comment: Recent investigative efforts by antirez (http://antirez.com/news/84) suggest that disabling THP helps: `echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled`